# jWebsocket Authentication - Connection is not rejected on invalid credentials

Tags: java, authentication, websocket

I tried to use the staticAuthProvider as shown [here](https://jwebsocket.org/documentation/reference-guide/authentication)
On the Server side It tells me 
    2015-01-14 10:57:21,353 WARN  - SystemPlugIn: Attempt to login with invalid credentials, username 'root'.

but If I send any data from the webpage, it arives at the websocket sucessfully. Do I have to Reject the connection on my own? How can I determine If the credentials are valid?
I can use

```
webSocketServerEvent.getConnector().getUsername()
```

to get the Username, but the problem is that at the beginning the username is "anonymous" and after a while it is "root"(if the credentials are correct).

I tried this in the processPacket method:

```
if (!webSocketServerEvent.getConnector().getUsername().equals("root")) {    
        webSocketServerEvent.getConnector().stopConnector(CloseReason.SERVER_REJECT_CONNECTION);
}
```

but this fails due that the username is anonymous at the beginning.
So every connection attempt is rejected

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to post this on [jWebSocket Forum?](http://jwebsocket.org/jwsForum219/forums/list.page)
I am sure someone would have answered you, I will make my try, but not sure if I get what you are looking for:

The fact that you are not authenticate does not mean that you don't have permissions on the server side to execute stuff, you will always have access to SystemPlugIn for example. Now, if you want the anonymous user to have no permissions, go ahead and edit the jWebSocket.xml file and set the anonymous user without any permissions, not sure if that helps, but try and then let us know.
Thanks,
Victor